# OneSignal Notification Listener

Tags: android, onesignal

**Requirement:

My app is in the foreground and open always. Now when a push is received, i need to listen and read parameters data.**

I have installed the latest version of Onesignal.

implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[5.0.0, 5.99.99]'.

But in my old code has following listener:

OneSignal.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(new OneSignal.OSNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler() {
@OverRide
public void notificationWillShowInForeground(OSNotificationReceivedEvent osNotificationReceivedEvent) {
}
});

After updating the version i have met an error. The listener its now working and shwoing a compilation error.
Cannot resolve method 'setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler' in 'OneSignal'

How can i dow it in latest version?.

Comment: It's recommended to format code in the questions in code block